# PyQt5 stops updating GUI within 30...300 seconds after start

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I develop a SCADA in python3 with the help of PyQt. I expect my program to continuously indicate various parameters received through RS-485 interface, however, within several minutes from the start (it is always a different time), the GUI stops to update itself. At the same time, the GUI stays responsive and if I were to click on one of the animated QAbstractButtons it has, the GUI starts to work as intended again for a short period of time. The problem occurs on both Linux and Windows.

The program has several worker threads: one for RS-485 exchange, one for reading/writing various data to disk, one for decoding received package and refreshing data in memory, one for request queue management, etc. They all work in loops of while (True): time.sleep(...) - do the job. The GUI is implemented in the main thread.

The data is indicated with QLabels. The QLabel.setText is added to painterEvent() of QWidgets containing the QLabels.

When the GUI stops updating, the other threads are up and running: the exchange is functioning, the request queue is forming, etc. Despite not being updated, the GUI stays responsive and reacts to QAbstractButton clicks.

I tried adding gui.update() or app.processEvents() into one of the worker threads, tried force updating through QTimer in the main thread. The result is the same: it works for a short while and then stops.

I tried increasing the time.sleep of the refresh thread and force updating the main widget over longer intervals of time (0.5 to 5 seconds) and it seems to help the situation a lot, this way it can run for several minutes, but it still does not solve the problem.

I would love to show the code, but the whole thing is way too bulky to post here and if I could narrow it down to a at least a hundred lines, I would have already solved the issue by now. So if any of you could at least share some general considerations on what to look for, I would be very happy.

**update:**
This seems to work, I'll leave it running for a few hours tomorrow to confirm:

```
update_timer = QTimer() 
update_timer.setSingleShot(False) 
update_timer.timeout.connect(self.gui.repaint) 
update_timer.setInterval(500) 
update_timer.start()
```

I assume that self.gui.update() did not work because dataChanged() was probably not emitted and control passed instead of doing repaint(). As far as I understand, the solution above is not the right way to update widgets.

So, the question actually boils down to the following:

What is the right way to update the main QWidget and how do I let the program know it needs to be redrawn, probably using dataChanged() signal?

Comment: A lot of text and no code. Why don't you make it the opposite so it is easier to help you? [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Never do anything related to PyQt from outside the main thread. Even if it seems the only logical way to do something.

After I 'fixed' the issue with the gui not being updated, I stumbled into a more serious problem: the program crashed every now and then. As it turns out, the GUI not being updated was only the top of the iceberg. The uptime was usually 2 to 7 minutes, I received a few glibc errors ("corrupted double-linked list" and "double free or corrution"). As it turns out, the source of the problem was inside refresh thread that has several hundreds of lines updating gui:

```
self.gui.screen_name.device_name.setCrash()
```

where setCrash() changes widget color and palette, or even more direct things like

```
self.gui.screen_name.label_name.setText(str(value))
```

I tracked down everything even loosely related to gui from the main file (the place where all the threading took place) and restyled it. Now it only has one worker thread - the RS-485, the rest are wrapped into separate QTimers.

This is what it was:

```
class Main():
    def __init__():
        self.plots_thread = Thread(target = self.plots_refresh)
        self.plots_thread.start()

    def plots_refresh():
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            #do stuff
```

And this is what it is now:

```
class Main():
    def __init__():
        self.plots_refresh_timer = QTimer()
        self.plots_refresh_timer.setSingleShot(False)
        self.plots_refresh_timer.timeout.connect(self.plots_refresh)
        self.plots_refresh_timer.setInterval(499) #prime number 
        self.plots_refresh_timer.start()

    def plots_refresh():
        #do stuff
```

This time the program has been running for over an hour and never crashed. After coming to conclusion that this was THE fix, I refactored the really messy test file and resumed testing - again, no troubles for half an hour.